# How to switch between k3s and minikube?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I have both k3s and minikube installed.
If I try

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

got

```
WARN[0000] Unable to read /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml, please start server with --write-kubeconfig-mode to modify kube config permissions 
error: error loading config file "/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml": open /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml: permission denied
```

Ok,I can fix this with

```
sudo k3s kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME      CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         default   default   default
```

I start minikube

```
minikube start
  minikube v1.30.1 on Ubuntu 22.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.26.3 on Docker 23.0.2 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

But how to switch to Minikube context?